# Ionic Application wifi error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have build up an Ionic application with cross platform which is IOS and Android.
But i have met some problem with the IOS device.

Some IOS device will display the error "No connect the internet" due to cannot login my application.

But another phone with same IOS have no this problem.

I really dun know how to debug this kind of bug@@

Comment: ionic version 1.x

Comment: You need to provide more details. Are you connected to the internet ? What is the code of your authentication procedure ?